# problemas al usar el api de instagram con node.js

Tags: nodejs, express, instagram

Estoy siguiendo un pequeño video donde explican como comunicarse al API de Instagram pero no he tenido éxito. Ya me cree la aplicación en instagram tengo el clienId y el clientSecret, estoy usando el paquete `node-instagram` de npm pero no logro hacer que me envién el token. en las URLque solicitan en la página de instagram exigen que sea del tipo `HTPPS` es decir, con certificado SSL, pero en mi local uso del tipo `HTTP`, esto tendrá algo que ver?

Acá dejo un trozo del código que estoy intentando:

```js
const Instagram = require('node-instagram').default;
const clavesInstagram = require('../../config/config').instagram;

const {clientId, clientSecret, accessToken}= clavesInstagram;
const redirectUri = 'http://localhost:3008/handleAuth';

const instagram = new Instagram({
    clientId: clientId,
    clientSecret: clientSecret
})

module.exports= {

    auth: (req, res)=> {
        console.log('\n\nAuth Controller...')
        res.redirect(
            instagram.getAuthorizationUrl(redirectUri, {
                scope: ['basic','likes'],
                state: 'your state'
            })
        )
    },

    handleauth: async (req, res)=> {
        try {
            console.log('\n\nHandleAuth....\n\n')
            const code = req.query.code; //código devuelto por Instagram
            const data= await instagram.athorizeUser(code, redirectUri);
            console.log('\n\nData Instagram:', data)
            res.json(data);
            
        } catch(e) {
            // statements
            console.log(e);
            res.json(e)
        }
    }

}
```

Quisiera ayuda por parte de alguien que haya hecho la conexión al API de instagram usando node.js ya que no se que mas intentar, tengo horas en esto y no he logrado avanzar. Gracias de antemano al que me pueda ayudar en esto, estaría muy agradecido.

PD: estoy probando con ngrok, este programa expone la url con https, pero sigo sin poder recibir el token instagram no me lo devuelve, no entiendo que estoy haciendo mal.